# what are the solutions of this biquadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

[image]
I tried to choose this equation but I don't know how to find the LCM

Comment: @ndruiven: that may be too advanced in this context, but $10(x^2-6)$ is certainly *a* common multiple, and that is all that is needed here

Comment: ah...good call.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Multiply the first fraction by $10/10$ and $\frac{x^2-6}{x^2-6}$.

Comment: can you explain how to multiply?

Comment: Recall multiplying any number by $\frac{n}{n}$ where $n \in \mathbb{R \setminus 0}$ will yield the same number. This is because any number divided by itself equals $1$. For example, $$\frac{2}{3} + \frac{2}{5} = (\frac{2}{3})(\frac{5}{5}) + (\frac{2}{5})(\frac{3}{3}) = \frac{2*5}{3*5} + \frac{2*3}{5*3} = \frac{10}{15} + \frac{6}{15} = \frac{16}{15}$$